# mkpath equivalent for chown [Perl]

Tags: perl, chown

How can I execute chown for all the directories on a given path (similar to mkpath in perl).

i.e. if I give /home/parth/something/else and  as input, all of the directories on this path will have that owner. 
Is there an inbuilt function ?

Comment: you do not need to change the owner of regular files? only directories?

Comment: yes only directories. Sorry for an unclear question. I meant, chnge owner for directories home, parth, something, else if above path is given.

Answer (score 4):

There are no built-in functions for it. However, you can use the core module [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) to traverse directory tree, [`getpwnam`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwnam.html) to get UID, and [`chown`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown.html) to change ownership.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub usage {
    die "Usage: $0 USERNAME PATH\n";
}

my $username = shift or die usage;
my $uid = ( getpwnam $username )[2] or die "Non-existent user.\n";

my $path = shift or die usage;
if ( !-e $path ) {
    die "Non-existent path.\n";
}

find( \&traverse, $path );

sub traverse {
    chown $uid, -1, $_ or die "Failed to chown [$_]: $!";
}
```

### Usage

```
chown_path USERNAME PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule) to identify the files to change, then use [`chown`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown.html) on the files found.

```
use File::File::Rule qw( );

my $uid = getpwnam('...') or die;
my $gid = getgrnam('...') or die;

for my $qfn (File::Find::Rule->in('/home/parth/something/else')) {
   chown($uid, $gid, $qfn)
      or warn("chown $qfn: $!\n");
}
```

Comment: @Alan Haggai Alavi, Thanks, I always get that backwards.